# Use performance counter for WCF hosted in many windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, performancecounter

I have a WCF hosted in a Windows Service.
Windows Service is installed many times (with different names) on the same server.
Various ASP.NET website calls the different Windows Service via Named Pipe to initialize WCF sessions.
I am trying to monitoring with a Performance Counter the number of instances initialized by every Windows Service but i can read also the number of instances hosted by the first of them.

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that i have the number of instances for the first but for the other services results always 0 instances (and this is not true because the service responds to calls correctly)..

Comment: Any code to show? [MCVE]. [ASK]

Comment: I added an image to better explain the situation.

Comment: Does anyone have ideas?